# should i create a vertical partition for geospatial data on a large table

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2012, geospatial, partitioning

I have a large table ( > 700,000 rows and growing) of contact data that includes:

- a polygon with spatial index
- 1000 character text field with full-text index
- about 25 other fields, some of which are used for searching (name, reference, id etc)

This table sees lots of queries on the polygon field and lots of separate queries on the free text field. (never both polygon and full-text in the same query).

We have recently been suffering from very poor performance from queries on this table and are considering creating a 'vertical partition' to put the spatial data in a new table and use a view to combine the two so the application sees the same data as before.

Will partitioning the table like this increase the performance of queries on the full-text and spatial indexes even if the results require the two tables to be joined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - yes.

After splitting the table in two, one with just the geometry it seems that the geometry queries are overall faster. The performance of the full text queries is about the same.

I suspect this is because the new table with only geometry data is much smaller and the queries on it have fewer indexes to choose from resulting in fewer execution plans.

BUT - querying a view that has a geometry column in one of the base tables works - but for some combinations of query area and spatial data density the spatial index was not selected and the performance was very slow. You cant pass an index hint for the spatial index to a query on a view so I ended up querying the base tables of the view directly in the end so I could force the use of the spatial index.